# get the record based on max value oracle multiple tables

Tags: database, oracle, max, record

i got problem with oracle query. in this query i want to show status resume where the record is taken by max value of seq coloumn and extern coloumn. this is my query:

```
select x.order_id, z.status_resume,
max(y.seq) as seq2,
max(y.extern_order_status) as extern
from t_order_demand x 
JOIN t_order_log y ON x.order_id=y.order_id
JOIN p_catalog_status z ON z.status_code_sc=y.extern_order_status
and x.order_id like '%1256%'
group by x.order_id, z.status_resume;
```

and this is the result: 
order id      status_resume         seq     extern

1256            proccess                        2             4

1256            registered                    1         2
1256            pre registered             0         1
i want the result just status resume based on max value from seq and extern. how can i do it? help me.. thanks.

order id      status_resume         seq     extern

1256            proccess                        2             4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH t AS
 (SELECT x.order_id
        ,z.status_resume
        ,MAX(y.seq) AS seq2
        ,MAX(y.extern_order_status) AS extern
  FROM   t_order_demand x
  JOIN   t_order_log y
  ON     x.order_id = y.order_id
  JOIN   p_catalog_status z
  ON     z.status_code_sc = y.extern_order_status
  AND    x.order_id LIKE '%1256%'
  GROUP  BY x.order_id
           ,z.status_resume)
SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  (t.seq || t.extern) = (SELECT MAX(tt.seq || tt.extern) FROM t tt);
```

Might work for you.

Comment: it works thanks a lot @ZsoltBotykai .. i edit a few things here "(t.seq2 || t.extern) IN (SELECT MAX(tt.seq2 || tt.extern) FROM t tt);" . thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH data AS 
( 
         SELECT   x.order_id, 
                  z.status_resume, 
                  Max(y.seq)                 AS seq2, 
                  Max(y.extern_order_status) AS extern 
         FROM     t_order_demand x 
         join     t_order_log y 
         ON       x.order_id=y.order_id 
         join     p_catalog_status z 
         ON       z.status_code_sc=y.extern_order_status 
         AND      x.order_id LIKE '%1256%' 
         GROUP BY x.order_id, 
                  z.status_resume ) 
SELECT * 
FROM   data 
WHERE  seq || extern = 
(select max(seq || extern) 
FROM   data)
/
```

A simple test case to validate :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 5, 7 FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT * FROM DATA
  6  where col1||col2 = (select max(col1||col2) from data)
  7  /

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         5          7

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic function RANK:

```
select order_id, status_resume, seq2, extern 
from (
    select x.order_id, z.status_resume,
           max(y.seq) as seq2,
           max(y.extern_order_status) as extern,
           rank() over(partition by x.order_id, z.status_resume order by max(y.seq) desc, max(y.extern_order_status) desc) rnk
    from t_order_demand x 
    JOIN t_order_log y ON x.order_id=y.order_id
    JOIN p_catalog_status z ON z.status_code_sc=y.extern_order_status
    and x.order_id like '%1256%'
    group by x.order_id, z.status_resume
) where rnk = 1;
```

But it's not clear what do you mean by max of two fields. There sum? The query above retrive the rows with `max seq` and if several rows have the same `seq` then only rows with `max extern_order_status` are retrieved.